# Access removable drives or shutdown a PC

Tags: windows-7, windows

Why would I want to restrict users from being able to access removeable drives or shutdown a PC?

Comment: You mean shutdown a PC? Is this in a corporate environment?

Answer (score 6):

> Why restrict shutdown

Perhaps the computer is providing some network service.  Perhaps it needs to stay online to perform some important batch job and you want to keep people from unconditionally shutting it down.

> Why restrict removeable drives

You want to block installation of software, theft of data, malware infections.

Comment: +1 Or updates, which are applied after hours.